# How to open a new tab with router.navigate in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, single-page-application, durandal

The following typescript code will always open in the current browser tab

```
navigate($data: menuItem, $event: JQueryEventObject) {
       //...
       let a = $event.currentTarget as HTMLAnchorElement;
       router.navigate(a.href);    
    }
```

How do I make router.navigate open in a **new** tab ? (that is when $event.ctrlKey is true)

Comment: For now I just use:  
`if ($event.ctrlKey) { window.open(url); }`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, as you @Daneille commented, you have to handle by your own way since durandal's router plugin ([navigate](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/master/src/plugins/js/history.js#L224) function) does not provide a way to open a new tab.

So it is better to handle something as you commented.

```
if ($event.ctrlKey) { 
    window.open(url); 
}
```

Comment: How do I retrieve url from the Router at least? What if somebody changes routes configuration afterwards?

Answer (score 51):

this is my solution

```
const url = this.router.serializeUrl(this.router.createUrlTree(['/my/url/route'], { queryParams: { ...anyQueryParamsYouWantOrOmitThis } }));
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Comment: Isn't this an Angular answer?

Comment: Admittedly I didn't see the tags on the question and just assumed they were asking about Angular based on the context of the code.   Clearly it's talking about the knockout.js framework called Durandal which uses similar syntax for route navigation, hence my confusion.

https://www.infoq.com/articles/durandal-javascript-framework/

Answer (score 23):

This one works with # hash (like https://example.com/#/users) and non-hash urls

```
openInNewTab(router: Router, namedRoute) {
    let newRelativeUrl = router.createUrlTree([namedRoute]);
    let baseUrl = window.location.href.replace(router.url, '');

    window.open(baseUrl + newRelativeUrl, '_blank');
}
```

Comment: Isn't this an Angular answer?

Comment: @xr280xr I think it is by virtue of Router being an angular class.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is better to do in HTML link  like this

```
<a  style=" text-decoration: none;" [routerLink]="['your-path',param1,param2]" target="_blank"  >your label </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
this.router.navigate([]).then((result) => {
  window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method as a replacement for router.navigate(...) for a new window:

```js
navigateNewWindow(router: Router, commands: any[]) {
    let baseUrl = window.location.href.replace(router.url, '');
    const url = new URL(commands.join("/"), baseUrl).href
    window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```