# How to open router.navigate /router link with query params in new tab

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I'm trying to navigate to a new tab on a click event, and I need to pass query param

```
<div  (click)="viewDetails()">view<div>
```

function

```
import { NavigationExtras, Router } from '@angular/router';

viewDetails(){
    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    queryParams: {
       "selectedAssessmentId": 10
    }
  };
 this.router.navigate(['./view'], navigationExtras)
}
```

Currently, am able to open in current tab. but, I need it to be open in new tab with query params. I tried with `[RouterLink]` also but faced the same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Routing navigate run in new tab(Use Angular Router naviagte )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521494/angular-2-routing-navigate-run-in-new-tabuse-angular-router-naviagte)

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47872931/9172668) answer

Comment: use routerlink instead in template  `<div   [routerLink]="['/view'', someDetails]" >view<div>` or 
 if you want to use code  component.ts  then `router.navigate(['/view'',someDetails]);`

Comment: @JoelJoseph how to pass query params

Comment: @arunkumar If you are using `[routerLink]`, then you can easily pass the quesryParams like: `<a target="_blank" [routerLink]="['../']" [queryParams]="{paramKey: 'paramValue'}">Click Me!</a>`

Answer (score 2):

you can use routerLink in your template

```
<a [routerLink]="['/view']" [queryParams]="{id: 10}" target="_blank">view</a>
```